# std::bad_alloc thrown when vector's push_back() is used

Tags: c++

In the following snippet of code, I get an error saying: 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)

This occurs at the push_back() instruction. What could be the reason? The error is seen in the first iteration itself so I do not think it is because the program has overused memory. I may be overlooking something really silly. Please let me know!

```
for(i=0; i<numsegs; i++){
    for(j=0;j<rvm->number_segs; j++){
        if(segbases[i] == rvm->segment_list[j]->ext_data_seg){
            transaction->rvm = rvm;
            transaction->tid = trans_count++;
            transaction->number_regs = 0;
            transaction->number_segs++;
            rvm->segment_list[j]->modified = 1;
            temp_seg = rvm->segment_list[j];                           
            transaction->segment_list.push_back(temp_seg);
        }
    }

}
```

The loop runs initially with numsegs = rvm->number_segs = 1.

EDIT:
The transaction structure is:

```
struct Trans_t{
    int tid;
    rvm_t rvm;
    int number_segs;
    int number_regs;
    vector <segment*> segment_list;
    vector <region*> region_list;   
};
typedef struct Trans_t* trans_t;
```

Comment: What is the type of `transaction`? Show us the definition of that type.

Comment: I just updated my post. transaction is of type trans_t

Comment: How dou you define `transaction`? Do you  allocate memory for it.

Comment: Yes. It is defined as: trans_t transaction = (trans_t)malloc(sizeof(trans_t));

Comment: You get `bad_alloc` when you run out of memory...

Comment: Well, I do not think I can run out of memory. This happens in the initial stage and does not even run for one full iteration. Could this be because I am allocating memory incorrectly or not handling vectors properly?

Comment: You shouldn't mix C and C++. Instead of `trans_t transaction = (trans_t)malloc(sizeof(trans_t))`, use `trans_t transaction = new trans_t;` if you really want to use pointers. But I am not sure that pointers are needed here... Modern C++ is aimed at avoiding manual memory management.

Comment: And when posting code, please remove unnecessary code (all those `printf()` calls...), these get into the way when reading.

Comment: @kebs Actually, this feels like an answer. Without proper operator `new` the allocated `trans_t` value is malformed (no constructors for vectors were run).

Comment: @oakad, yep, you got that ! I didn't even notice this! So, best advice for @user2984490: forget about `malloc()` when using standard library containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem appears to be stated in comments: if indeed structure of type `Trans_t` (which is not POD) is allocated using malloc (as OP commented), then the whole program is malformed.

As constructors for the Trans_t::segment_list<> were never run, trying to push anything into it will cause either crash or exception. Here, it is quite possible that the "value size" parameter passed to standard allocator exceeds `max_size()` of that allocator (because it's essentially garbage in), so it throws bad_alloc upon receiving it as argument.

Comment: Thank you @oakad! I used new to allocate memory and changed the definition of structure so that it is not always a pointer. This seems to have fixed the problem for now. :)